# Query to result execution plan in SQL Server 2008 out of SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

Hi friends is there a query something like `select * from [stored proc]` which returns execution plan of SQL statement in XML format...I don't want to use SSMS .

Comment: If you don't want to use SSMS, what will you be using?  A custom app (C#, Java, etc.), sqlcmd script, ...?  Are you looking for the actual plan (after executing the code) or an estimated plan (without executing the code)?  Are you looking for the plan of a whole batch of statements, a single TSQL statement, a Stored Provedure, ...?  More details would help.

Comment: a stored procedure, i will a custom app in C#..i am looking for estimated plan...idea is to compare two estimated plans of a same stored procedure executed in 2005 and 2008 servers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the XML query plan by using  [sys.dm_exec_cached_plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187404.aspx) and [sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326654.aspx).

```
select x.query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans as p
  cross apply sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(p.plan_handle,  0, -1) as x
where p.objtype = 'proc' and
      x.objectid = object_id('StoredProcName', 'P')
```

Comment: Mikael instead of passing the procedure name can when pass something like a statment (exec 'procname')

Comment: @sqlnewbie - No. This will get the actual execution plan not the estimated one.